# Run a sqoop job on a specific queue

Tags: hadoop, queue, sqoop

I'm trying to create a **Sqoop job run in a specific queue** but it doesn't work.

I've tried two things :

**1st** : Declare the queue in the job creation

```
sqoop job \
         --create myjob \
         -- import \
         --connect jdbc:teradata://RCT/DATABASE=MYDB \
         -Dmapred.job.queue.name=shortduration \
         --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \
         --username DBUSER -P \
         --query "$query" \
         --target-dir /data/source/dest/$i \
         --check-column DAT_CRN_AGG \
         --incremental  append \
         --last-value 2001-01-01 \
         --split-by NUM_CTR
```

But it throws a parsing argument error due to `-Dmapred.job.queue.name=shortduration`

**2nd** : remove the `-Dmapred.job.queue.name=shortduration` of the job creation. job creation works well. But unable to specify which queue should be used

I'm loosing hope to run my job in this queue

Thanks for any help provided !

**EDIT** : get an import working with `sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=shortduration` but sqoop job not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have an error in your command

```
-Dmapreduce.job.queuename=NameOfTheQueue
```

note queuename one word and the order, based on the documentation, vm args need to go directly after the import.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_generic_and_specific_arguments

> Generic Hadoop command-line arguments:
>   (must preceed any tool-specific arguments)
>   Generic options supported are
>   -conf      specify an application configuration file
>   -D             use value for given property

```
sqoop job -Dmapred.job.queuename=shortduration \
         --create myjob \
         -- import  \
         --connect jdbc:teradata://RCT/DATABASE=MYDB \
         --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \
         --username DBUSER -P \
         --query "$query" \
         --target-dir /data/source/dest/$i \
         --check-column DAT_CRN_AGG \
         --incremental  append \
         --last-value 2001-01-01 \
         --split-by NUM_CTR
```

you might just want to try it with the import tool to see if it is working correctly then do the job command ie

```
sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queuename=shortduration \
         --connect jdbc:teradata://RCT/DATABASE=MYDB \
         --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \
         --username DBUSER -P \
         --query "$query" \
         --target-dir /data/source/dest/$i \
         --check-column DAT_CRN_AGG \
         --incremental  append \
         --last-value 2001-01-01 \
         --split-by NUM_CTR
```

Comment: still have the same error `Unrecognized argument: -Dmapred.job.queuename=shortduration
` ... I don't understand what is going wrong

Comment: Finally get an import working with the queue using `sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=shortduration ...`

Comment: Yes of course but it does not work. I think it's a bit more complicated to give a queue in a create job ...