# Sqoop queue scheduling

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, sqoop

I'm trying to run the following sqoop import

```
sqoop import \
        -Dmapred.child.java.opts="\-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom" \
        -Dmapred.job.queuename=batch \
        --connect $connection \
        --username $username \
        --password $password \
        --table $sourceTable \
        --columns "$columns"\
        --hive-import \
        --hive-overwrite \
        --hive-table $targetTable \
        --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
        --hive-delims-replacement "SPECIAL" \
        --null-string '\\N' \
        --null-non-string '\\N' \
        -m 1
```

Although I assigned queuename to batch, when I run the sqoop command, it assigns the job to 'default' queue instead.

I'm checking the jobs at the resource-manager (node-master:8088).

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Sqoop job in specific queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676075/run-a-sqoop-job-on-a-specific-queue)

Answer (score 0):

The `mapred.job.queuename` option is not valid. Instead, use `mapreduce.job.queuename` or `mapred.job.queue.name`(deprecated)