# Sqoop incremental import argument order?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to import an incremental load using sqoop from mysql. Below is the command I am running on unix console:

```
    sqoop job \
    --create sample_job --import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=realtime \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull \
    --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
    --table SAMPLE_TABLE -m 1 \
    --username tony \
    --password stark \
    --incremental lastmodified \
    --check-column ts \
    --last-value 2018-04-24 \
    --target-dir /some/tmp/location/ \
    --map-column-hive XYZ=tinyint \
    --null-string '\\N' \
    --null-non-string '\\N'
```

But, getting a typical argument error :

```
     /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91//sqoop/conf/sqoop-env.sh: line 21: HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${hcat -classpath}: bad substitution
     Warning: /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
     Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
     18/04/25 11:24:52 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.4.0-91
     18/04/25 11:24:52 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for job:
```

I found lot of resources available which show how to run imports with commands but most sources do not show the exact command lines and have improper arguments passed. I saw somewhere that the order of arguments matter , and so tried switching the order but didnt work. It is a simple issue so can someone tell me the proper syntax ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your syntax. https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1769640

```
$ sqoop job --create myjob -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://example.com/db \
--table mytable
enter code here
```

There a space between first parameter, replace your command with a space before import parameter.

```
sqoop job \
--create sample_job -- import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=realtime \
--connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--table SAMPLE_TABLE -m 1 \
--username tony \
--password stark \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column ts \
--last-value 2018-04-24 \
--target-dir /some/tmp/location/ \
--map-column-hive XYZ=tinyint \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to run it but had to remove -Dmapred.job.queue.name=realtime argument for it to work. Any idea how to include it too?

Comment: @StrangerThinks, try to add parameter of the saved job when executing it: `sqoop job --exec sample_job -- -Dmapred.job.queue.name=realtime`.

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander thanks. I was able to solve the issue

Comment: @StrangerThinks does my solution help you?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander I am still getting this error:

18/04/27 13:47:17 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.4.0-91
18/04/27 13:47:19 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
18/04/27 13:47:19 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -Dmapred.job.queue.name=realtime

I am running the command through ESPX. However, I decided I dont need the queue parameter in my current environment. So, not necessary but it would be good to know how to get around this error.

Comment: I thinks you will define queue before create a job, you can find an example here : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676075/run-a-sqoop-job-on-a-specific-queue

Comment: @LoisTHS Thanks. It went through when kept before anything else... 

        sqoop job -Dmapred.job.queue.name=realtime --meta-connect "jdbc:hsqldb:file:/tmp/sqoop-meta.db;shutdown=true" -exec <job_name>

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. Parameter needs to be passed during exec and the order should be as follows:

```
sqoop job -Dmapred.job.queue.name=realtime --meta-connect "jdbc:hsqldb:file:/tmp/sqoop-meta.db;shutdown=true" -exec
```